# Recursively remove files those size is less than 1MB

Tags: bash

How do I recursively remove files that are less than 1MB in size from a directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete all files smaller than a certain size in all subfolders?](http://superuser.com/questions/644272/how-do-i-delete-all-files-smaller-than-a-certain-size-in-all-subfolders)

Answer (score 25):

This can be done with `find`:

```
find . -type f -size -1M -exec rm {} +
```

Note that this will recursively descend into subdirectories, and will unconditionally delete all files smaller than 1 megabyte.  Be careful.

Comment: you're missing the path argument to `find`

Comment: @Useless: That's GNU `find`. :)

Comment: I never knew it let you omit that!

Comment: @Useless: It does, but other versions of `find` don't, so if you want portability, you should include a directory argument.

Comment: I would recommend `-delete` instead of `-exec rm`, since the latter will have corner-case problems with file names contaning weird characters (even newlines could appear), but mostly since it will die if the number of files is very large (>`getconf ARG_MAX`). This has happened to me when using `rm *` to clear a browser cache directory, and I think it applies in this case as well (if not, please feel free to tell me why).

Comment: @DanielAndersson: `find` restricts the number of arguments to the called process to fit into the system's limits, in contrast to `rm *`, which is guranteed to be a single process invocation.  `find` will invoke multiple instance of `rm` if necessary.  And I'm pretty sure that special characters are treated correctly, including newline characters.  I prefer `-exec rm` over `-delete` for flexibility reasons -- as an example, the latter offers no way to delete write-protected files.

Comment: You are correct, and I thank you for your comment. `-exec +` takes ARG_MAX into account, and I have not seen any file name problems with `{}` in `find`.

Comment: @Invoker: I reverted your change since it was incorrect.  `-1M` means less than one megabyte as desired.  Your version would delete all files with exactly one megabyte in size, which seems to be a somewhat pointless operation.

Comment: For anyone interested, if you want to remove all files _greater than_ 1M, use the command `find . -type f -size +1M -exec rm {} +`. Note the +1M instead of -1M.

Answer (score 11):

This should do the job:

```
$ find <directory> -type f -size -1M -delete
```

Comment: I don't think we need to out hyphen in from of 1M.

Comment: @Invoker, I believe the `-` sign is a minus sign meaning "less than 1M". If you run `find <directory> -type f -size +1M -delete` you will delete all files _larger than_ 1M.

Comment: yes you are right my bad

Answer (score 2):

Just for variety and a possible (probably marginal) performance gain:

```
find <directory> -type f -size -1M -print0  | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: How is this supposed to be faster?  It starts an additional `xargs` process.

Comment: Now you can have _two_ CPUs contending for the same block device!  More sensibly, the stat/readdir operations aren't synchronously blocked by the unlink operation.  Whether this is likely to be better obviously depends on the subtree size, number of files, device etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try

> find . -size -1M -exec rm {}  \;

Comment: This is great for non-GNU users.  Thanks!  the same as @Sven's answer, but with `\;` at the end instead of `+`

Answer (score -1):

You can checkout this link http://ayaz.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/bash-quickly-deleting-empty-files-in-a-directory/ , it has exactly what you want.

```
for file in *;
  do
    file_size=$(du $file | awk '{print $1}');
    if [ $file_size == 0 ]; then
        echo "Deleting empty file $file with file size $file_size!";
        echo "rm -f $file";
    fi;
done
```

You can iterate through all the files with a for loop and then use du and awk to find the filesize like in the above example.

Comment: Answers on SO should be self-contained -- don't post a mere link.  (Moreover, the code in the linked post deletes empty files rather than files smaller than 1M.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach can't we use $file_size < 1M in the given code example link.

Comment: No, we can't, since the shell won't understand `1M`.

Comment: By 1M I meant 1048576 converting 1MB to byte

Comment: Well, if you test if this really works and copy the code to your answer, this might become an SO answer.